# ZF3 What to do with getServiceLocator()->get('translator') in AbstractContoller

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I have an abstract controller in my app (ZF3) which extends all my module controllers.

I'm calling here my base translator and apply the translator also per module but as getServiceLocator() is removed from ZF3 I'm wonder what I can do to create a $this->translator in that extended controller.

This what I used in ZF2:

```
$this->translator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');
```

I have found these docs but this is seems another purpose to me.

https://zendframework.github.io/zend-mvc/migration/to-v2-7/#servicelocatoraware-initializers

Comment: Actually, your link specifies exactly what you have to do. Just read after "To prepare your code...". If I find time, I will try to answer with specific code to your case. Note, you may have to inject the translator for each controller in its own factory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out with (a working) example! I'm really figuring it out and will read again about what you said and debug and re-debug all out of it!

Comment: I'm still struggling here as the examples talsk about containers and the examples (which are not completely usable for me) just put a foldername in there, etc. Even when using a factory can this be done on multiple ways ?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to overcome this problem.

First solution that comes in mind, which is more of a quick fix than anything else, is to inject the service locator in every controller.
In order to do that, you'll need to inject it through the constructor and change your factory for controllers (factories if many of them).

As you do that, yoou can only inject the translator rather than the container (service manager).

Initializers are indeed a way to go, but they might be removed later on. I would probably rather use a [delegator](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-servicemanager/delegators/). This way, you do not have to inject through the constructor, but you'll need to inject through a setter, meaning you introduce temporal coupling...

Comment: Thanks! The most proper way seems to be inject it in every controller, so only where you need it. I'm looking for (working) examples as I'm new to that and indeed need a quick fix to keep going.

I found some othert solution that cannot be used as well as controller_plugins will be removed in ZF4, but his tutorial is perfectly!

https://daredevel.com/2017/04/to-setup-translate-controller-plugin-zend-framework-3/

Comment: You can go with the way proposed in the tutorial, it's definitely valid for ZF3. In ZF4, we will probably only have PSR7/PSR15 actions, so definitely no plugin. If you want to go that way, use middleware routes and inject your translator where needed.

Comment: I'm sure I need to go the factory way, I still need a proper example to make sure I'm going the right way because it seems people do it even different ways using factories.